# How do I override the rendering of UITextField when the field has started editing

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I've created a subclass of UITextField with a picker as the input view. I want the text field to show as two lines with a time on line one and day on line two. Like this:

[image: UITextView with two lines]

To do this I overrode the drawText method as follows:

```
override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.alignment = .left
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    let attrs = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12),
                 NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle,
                 NSForegroundColorAttributeName: Utilities.COLOR_alarmText]
    (self.text! as NSString).draw(in: rect, withAttributes: attrs)
}
```

This is great and I'm happy with this. HOWEVER when I tap into the field  the text field re-renders using a different draw method. So it then looks like this:

[image: UITextField when you tap to edit]

QUESTION: Is there a way that I can override some other method (I've looked at the API and haven't found anything) to keep my two lined field?

Comment: You mentioned "I've created a subclass of UITextField with a picker as the input view " and textfield still can be edited via keyboard isn't it suppose to get input from picker?

Comment: Yes. Editing all works as desired. The picker shows and you can select the various items in the picker components. I've even got a toolbar that appears and all works fine. I've even stopped the ability to actually change the text, so you can only use the picker and toolbar to influence the value - and when this changes the text field's value is updated.

The only issue is the rendering when in edit mode.

Comment: I am not sure if its being used anywhere else also with different behaviour in app But I would have use a different control such as UIButton or text view for this type of functionality so I could also use attributedString

Comment: Can the UIButton easily be rendered to look like a UITextField and when tapped can I open the keyboard (picker in my case)? Can UIButton be multiple lines? I'm just starting with iOS, so not sure which is the best way to go. I don't want a UITextView as it will introduce other complications.

Comment: The answer to your all question is YES except keyboard as I thought you wanted to show picker. In this case UIbutton is the bestsellers way unless you want to show keyboard also.

Comment: I'd still like to know why I can't control the rendering of the text when in edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this I would recommend to use UIButton instead of UITextfield as you want to pick from piker not keyboard and also don't want editing behaviour

Comment: How do you get the button to show an inputView? It is a get only property of UIButton. Or is there another way to show the picker? With my UITextField, tapping the field automatically opens the picker as the inputView (aka keyboard?).

Comment: I've ended up implementing what you've suggested @Imran. I used this [project](https://github.com/nicolas-miari/EditableButton), which I found in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429900/uibutton-and-picker-view). It's not too bad, but I was not able to do a blink cursor to help the user understand which field is being edited.   
  
I still think someone must know how to affect the UITextField rendering when in edit.