# iOS - UIButton become first responder to open keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, becomefirstresponder

I need to open keyboard on button click for UIButton (not using/for UITextField). I have tried to create custom button by overriding variable `canBecomeFirstResponder` but it's not working.

Is there any other way to do so?

**Note:** I want to set UIPIckerView as an input view of UIButton in key board frame.

Here is my code.

```
class RespondingButton: UIButton {


    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }


    private func commonInit() {
        // common init
    }



}
```

In my view controller, I connected button action.

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBAction func testBecomeFirstResponder(button: RespondingButton){
      button.becomeFirstResponder()  // Not working.
   } 
}
```

Comment: Do you want to use a keyboard to change data shown by UIPicker?

Comment: @Phyber You may know, we can set UIPickerView as an inputView for UITextField, just similar way, I need to do it with UIButton

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIBUTTON and picker view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429900/uibutton-and-picker-view)

Comment: Maybe this is weired, but what is about a hidden textfield and set this to first responder - just if nothing else is working for you.

Comment: @Retterdesdialogs, I have this choice in my mind but this would be last choice for me to get it work.

Comment: For sure, because of that I asked very kindly :)

Comment: @dan Thanks dear, it's working...

Answer (score 2):

Add conformance to UIKeyInput like this. It should work.

```
class RespondingButton: UIButton, UIKeyInput {

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }

    var hasText: Bool = true
    func insertText(_ text: String) {}
    func deleteBackward() {}
}
```

Comment: Partially means?

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I would do.

1. Create transparent `textField` 1x1px, lets say it is `myTextField`.
2. Then add your desired button. In the button action make the `myTextField.becomeFirstResponder()`.

Create view:

```
let pvBackground: UIView = {
        let v = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10))
        v.backgroundColor = .white
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
}()
```

In `viewDidLoad`:

```
pvBackground.addSubview(yourPickerView)//add the picker into the pvBackground
myTextField.inputView = pvBackground
```

I added the `pickerView` into the another view to be able to customize it more.