# UIbutton doesn't respond to touch events

Tags: ios, uibutton

My view hierarchy is something like this:

```
UIView -> UIStackView
             -> UIView
                -> PlayerView
             -> UIView
                -> UIStackView
                   UITextField (title)
                   UIButton (close)
                   UIButton (settings) etc...
```

My problem is following...When screen loads, if I click on the  close or settings buttons it WORKS.

The problem is if I click first to the Player View to play video, then I stop a video and when I tap on any of the UIButtons it doesn't work. Button is active, but touch event doesn't fire.
You can see player implementation here:
[github playerview example](https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer-sdk-ios-demo/blob/master/JWPlayer-SDK-iOS-Demo/SwiftViewController.swift)

The weird thing is...if I click on the UITextField (Title) then I'm able to click on the UIButtons again, and touch events are firing.

I have played with adding `isUserInteractionEnabled = true` to the UIView where I have the buttons but it didn't work.

[here is a screenshot of UI debug tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ez33D.png)

[Player view object inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXlYj.png)

[Player view hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAlvn.png)

Comment: Check if any other view is covering the buttons. Also, add the relevant code.

Comment: @PGDev no other views covering, it would not work at all. Buttons work if I don't click to the other view (UIView -> PlayerView)

RushabhCShah i was setting isUserInteractionEnabled = true on the view, but it didn't work.

Comment: You need to enable UserInteraction method in parent of PlayerView.

Comment: Please share your UI with debugger mode and maybe share some code for better understand.

Comment: @EmreCiftci added image to the ui debbugger mode...i think the problem is somewhere in the player view since it is a UIWebView. After i click on player I'm unable to click on the below buttons on the UIView below.

Comment: I mean share tapped and stopped PlayerView hierarchy with UI debugger mode. I want to see the view hierarchy in this situation.

Comment: @EmreCiftci added some more info, not sure if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Is the video playing in a separate window? Note there is only one window that is the key window and only key window can receive events.

Comment: @Sulthan video plays in the same window

Comment: Is that button's height width are okay?

Comment: For every superview (super superview, super super superview, etc) the button has, set the 'clipsToBounds" property to true. Can you still see the button?

Answer (score 2):

Whether a control reacts to an event (e.g. a touch), depends on whether it is the [first responder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/using_responders_and_the_responder_chain_to_handle_events).
If the event is a touch, the UI element in which the touch occurred, becomes the 1st responder. This applies e.g. to an `UIButton`.
Since your buttons work as long as you did not play a video, this means that they are user interaction enabled, and the target action is assigned.
When you played and stopped a video, and only the `UITextField` but no button can become 1st responder, this means to me that only the `UITextField` is a view that can be tapped, but not the `UIButtons`. So the `UIButtons` must be covered by some other view that does not respond to the tap.
To check this, I suggest that you stop your app at a breakpoint, and tap in the Xcode debug area the Debug View Hierarchy button:

[image]

Then, you should see if your buttons are covered by something else.

EDIT:

One more idea: Maybe for some reason the property `canBecomeFirstResponder` of your button is not `true` (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621130-canbecomefirstresponder)). Please check this in the debugger. If it is `false`, you might have success by setting it explicitly to `true`. To do so, you had to subclass your button, and override this `var` as

```
override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
  return true
}
```

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45491770/1987726).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Reinhard. I have added the player view hierarchy above you can check last link. Unfortunately I don't see anything overlapping on the buttons.

Comment: I have tried to setup `canBecomeFirstResponder` but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. The selectedRateView had a height constraint of 0 with a priority of 1000. This caused the view to have a height of 0 even though the code was trying to set it's frame. For some reason, the child controls were still visible; but not receiving events.

For some reason, this wasn't being enforced on older versions of iOS. The selectedRateView was the height specified when setting the frame in code and it's children were receiving touch events.